# What does "strap" mean in this context?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, integrated-circuit, layout

This is one common error in layout IC. What does "strap" mean in this context?

> LUP.6 { @ Any point inside NMOS source/drain space to the nearest PW
> STRAP in the same PW <= 30 um @ Any point inside PMOS source/drain
> space to the nearest NW STRAP in the same NW <= 30 um

This is an example: 
https://community.cadence.com/cadence_technology_forums/f/digital-implementation/47259/regarding-to-lup-6-error-in-drc-for-digital-circuit-p-r

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case, a "strap" refers to a low-impedance connection between the substrate and a power rail, in order to provide a stable substrate voltage at the body of a MOSFET.

If this impedance is too high, then a parasitic PNPN structure formed between the power rails can act as a parasitic thyristor under certain conditions, leading to a short circuit and severe chip damage. This risk is *especially* high for transistors in the I/O (rather than core) region of the chip, as they are exposed to sudden voltages and transients from the outside world.

In the following diagram, it's clear that a single pFET and a single nFET are enough to create this positive feedback structure (adapted and extended from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latch-up#/media/File:Latchup.png)):

[image]

The sensitivity and gain of this structure are determined by doping, geometry, and most importantly Rp and Rn (the resistance of your strap connection). If they are small enough, then the bases of the parasitic BJTs are held at the rails and latchup is prevented. If these resistances are too large, then a sudden event can cause the N-well or P-sub voltage to drift away from the supply rails, turning on the parasitic BJTs. Because of the unfortunate way they are cross-coupled, they will remain on until either power is removed, or the chip is so damaged that the PNPN structure or a supply rail are physically no longer present. Under these conditions, your chip simply stops being electrical engineering and starts being metallurgy.

In the case of an nFET sitting in P-substrate or a P reverse-well, a strap is typically a P-implanted diffusion area connected to VSS; in the case of a pFET sitting in an N-well, this is an N-implanted diffusion area typically connected to VDD (or perhaps a specific VDD for that power domain if you have multiple).

The violation you have, LUP.6 (**L**atch-**up** rule 6) indicates that there is no such strap near the offending transistor. While 30 um is the maximum distance, it is encouraged to place a strap, or perhaps an entire guard ring, as close as possible<sup>1</sup> to the transistor. Of course, the strap must have a substrate connection to the transistor in question, so it must be in the same well if applicable.

Here is an example showing some various ways of creating a strap, in this case using a 180nm mixed-signal process:

nFETs (P-substrate, source/drain are implanted N+, strap is implanted P+):

[image]

pFETs (N-well, source/drain are implanted P+, strap is implanted N+):

[image]

Note that in the pFET case, additional n-well region is drawn to enclose the strap completely, in the same N-well as the transistor.

Note that for I/O transistors that connect to bond pads, additional rules often apply. While the rules deck I use is under NDA, you can typically expect that each I/O transistor will require far more protection, perhaps mandating guard rings instead of simple straps, or even requiring specific combinations of both to mitigate the kinds of outside signals that can induce latchup.

<sup>1</sup>As close as possible without compromising other layout or performance concerns